# MVC5 Vanilla Layouts No Show

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to build my first MVC5/Razor application from scratch, rather than including all of the bloat you get when you include all references from the get-go.

I've got a Views folder with a Home and a Shared folder. Home containing Index.cshtml and the Shared folder containing the _Layout.cshtml. The Content folder containing the Site.css and the bootstrap.css is at route.

**EDIT**
I cannot get the style sheet to work with the MVC build. Currently there's no styling affecting the Index page, I've done tests to see if the layout page is being put to use and it is, but for some reason the css isn't being utilised.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong and have included my reference paths of each file below. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Some App </title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Comment: You neglected to mention what your actual problem is.

Comment: Apologies, was cut/paste, missed a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you and Chris have already hit on it, that the bundling is the issue.

I agree that you don't want to be using all of Microsoft's stuff or even having it there if you're not using it, but for the sake of all the 'ball ache' of making everything work from scratch, I'd remove the stuff you don't want from the ready made MVC, ie: get rid of the OWIN ref.

Without seeing more code I can't help further, but if you need a quick fix:

Whack the below in your _Layout.cshtml `<head>`

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

**Update**

Quick thought - have you got `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);` in your Global.asax? If you haven't, that's why it isn't working.

Comment: Ah yes, completely missed out the Global.asax! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Styles.Render` and `Scripts.Render` aren't specific to bundling. They simply include the appropriate HTML tag to reference the specified file. The bundling framework in MVC actually creates literal files at that location when it does its work. In other words it's two separate pieces of functionality.

My guess is that you're not actually having the bundles created in the first place, and therefore the reference files don't exist. Bundling in MVC requires the [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/), so make sure you have that installed.

Also, FWIW, there really isn't that much "bloat" in the MVC project template. Aside from jQuery-UI, which I always remove, pretty much everything else is necessary and will have to be added sooner or later, anyways.

Comment: Was just looking into the bundling, thanks for pointing out where it is! I had installed it, but I think it could be something else to do with the bundling and that I'm not correctly handling it elsewhere.

The bloat I was referring to, but made a hash of, was the security stuff, OWIN, I've created my own custom security for Web Forms and wanted to try my hand with MVC.

Comment: Identity + OWIN is entirely optional. If you don't want it included, just disable authentication when creating your project.